# How can I get a ComponentManger object in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Directly `import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager` in java file does  not work.

`atlassian-create-jira-plugin-module` then choosing **Component Import** and specifying com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager does not, either.

I have looked into some tutorial and just does not get the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ComponentAccessor` class.

The answer for Jira 5.0 is here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/73426/how-do-i-import-com-atlassian-jira-componentmanager.